# How to make Three figures in one horizontal Line in Latex?

Tags: graphics, line-breaking

I am trying to make these three figures in one horizontal line using overleaf latex but it is not giving me the desired results, here is the example code

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
  \centering
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=3.2in]{fig4a.png}}
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=3.2in]{fig4b.png}}
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=3.2in]{fig4c.png}}
  \caption{desired caption}
  \label{fig_4}
\end{figure*}
```

Example output, here each box is the example of image
[image]

Desired output
[image]

Where do I go wrong?, Please I need your assistant

Comment: you have not provided any code we can test but you are asking for a total of 9.6in plus two word spaces to fit across one line. How wide is your text width?

Comment: you don't need to use subfigure, you could just have three `\includegraphics`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code snippet to complete small, but compilable document which reproduce your problem. It seems that you use in deprecated package `subfigure`. Replace it with `subfig` (or `subcaption`). Also it is seems, that your images are to wide that can be placed in one line.

Comment: Any news? You receive two answers, you should award one of them with acceptance (by clicking on check mark at top left side of the answer, which solve your problem on the best way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, if the width of your figures exceeds the maximum width of your document so if you change the width values in `\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=3.2in]{fig4a.png}}`. Then the figures can stay together side by side.

Comment: Thank you @Ali for this good contribution

Comment: works very well

Answer (score 1):

Your code sniped :

- It seems that your images are to wide that can be fit in one line. As a cure define their width as fraction of the text width (since all have the same width, you can use keys Gin (See MWE below)
- In code you use `\subfigure[]{...}`, which are defined by deprecated package `subfigure`.
- Since your in code fragment aren't present subcaptions, there is no reason to use `subfigure` or packages by which it is replaced (`subfig` or even better is to use `subcaptions`).
- Please, in future questions always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but complete document, which compilation reproduce your problem).

An example of MWE can serve:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
\centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.32\linewidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{fig4a.png}}  % we haven't your images ...
\hfill
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{fig4b.png}}
\hfill
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{fig4c.png}}
    \caption{desired caption}
\label{fig_4}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders in your document)

Comment: Thank you very much, very usefully, appreciate!